# Here.com API returns incorrect country code NCY

Tags: here-api

Request: https://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?app_id=APP_ID&app_code=APP_CODE&mode=retrieveAreas&prox=35.1377685%2C33.9196697%2C1000&language=en&gen=9

Replace these two by actual values: APP_ID, APP_CODE

This is response:

```json
{
   "Response":{
      "MetaInfo":{
         "Timestamp":"2019-05-06T10:31:19.317+0000"
      },
      "View":[
         {
            "_type":"SearchResultsViewType",
            "ViewId":0,
            "Result":[
               {
                  "Relevance":1.0,
                  "Distance":-1092.5,
                  "Direction":149.7,
                  "MatchLevel":"city",
                  "MatchQuality":{
                     "Country":1.0,
                     "County":1.0,
                     "City":1.0,
                     "PostalCode":1.0
                  },
                  "Location":{
                     "LocationId":"NT_iVkNRSYU-2l2WyhtuOg9TB",
                     "LocationType":"area",
                     "DisplayPosition":{
                        "Latitude":35.13116,
                        "Longitude":33.9244
                     },
                     "MapView":{
                        "TopLeft":{
                           "Latitude":35.16061,
                           "Longitude":33.88137
                        },
                        "BottomRight":{
                           "Latitude":35.08291,
                           "Longitude":33.95569
                        }
                     },
                     "Address":{
                        "Label":"Karakol, Turkish-Cypriot Administered Area",
                        "Country":"NCY",
                        "County":"Famagusta",
                        "City":"Karakol",
                        "PostalCode":"99450",
                        "AdditionalData":[
                           {
                              "value":"Turkish-Cypriot Administered Area",
                              "key":"CountryName"
                           },
                           {
                              "value":"Famagusta",
                              "key":"CountyName"
                           }
                        ]
                     },
                     "MapReference":{
                        "ReferenceId":"970895970",
                        "MapId":"UEAM19108",
                        "MapVersion":"Q1/2019",
                        "MapReleaseDate":"2019-04-15",
                        "SideOfStreet":"neither",
                        "CountryId":"26569036",
                        "CountyId":"26569038",
                        "CityId":"26571374"
                     }
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

See "Country" field:
"Country":"NCY",

As you can see, country code is NCY. I'm trying to find what country uses that 3-letter code and I can't find it anywhere on the internet.
https://www.worldatlas.com/aatlas/ctycodes.htm

It looks like this is some API issue and it returns wrong country code.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no official answer from HERE, I'll give at least some background info.
NCY is probably a non ISO 3166-1-alpha-3 code that represents Northern Cyprus.

Cyprus is a complicated case, with Greece and Turkey claiming influence. I remember 4 zones modeled, a Greek part, a Turkish part, the UN controlled demilitarized zone in between and a British military base.
You can read more at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyprus#Administrative_divisions

Comment: Yes, I agree it should be reported as a bug. But after I reported it to support they sent me to stackoverflow and told here maps team is here and will fix it if this is really bug. So I did like they instructed me. Don’t know where else I can report it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go a step further and say this should be filed as a bug, for two reasons.

According to the [API Reference](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/topics/resource-type-response-geocode.html#resource-type-response-geocode__address), the Address object type is as follow (emphasis mine):

> `Label`   Assembled address value for displaying purposes.
>
> `Country` **ISO 3166-alpha-3 country code**
>
> [...]

As you noticed, and this is the first reason of why it is a bug, `NCY` is not a valid ISO 3166-alpha-3 country code

Furthermore, your request does not contain the [politicalview](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/topics/resource-reverse-geocode.html) query parameter, which allows to deal with disputed territories: for exemple, Crimea would be returned as part of Russia if `politicalview=RUS` is in the request. If `politicalview` is not specified, the API assumes the "international view".

However, and this is the second reason, the so-called "Turkish Republic of North Cyprus" is recognized only by Turkey. It does not make sense to return a country code other than `CYP`, except when `politicalview=TUR` is specified in the request.